# Angular 4 How to filter array by multiple conditions?

Tags: angular

I have a component that displays an array of a specific type that looks like:

```
export class Demo implements IDemo {
    public id: string,
    public name,
    public status: string,
    public type: string
}
```

I'd like to enable the users to filter this by selecting multiple names, statuses and types and hit a filter-button:

```
private filterDemoRowsById() {
    this.demoRows = Array.from(this.demoFilter(this.selectedIds.map(function(x) { return x; }), this.demoRows));
    this.filteredByIds = true;
}

private demoFilter(query, rowsToFilter: Demo[]) {
    return rowsToFilter(function (item) {
        return query.indexOf(item.Demo.id) >= 0;
    });
}
```

I'll have a working solution (see code above) for one filter but I'd like your input on how to combine multiple filters. If a filter for "id" has been applied I'd like to only filter those rows when selecting one or more status-filters etc

Any suggestions?